# Margins only displaying on document pages, not master pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I'm running into a problem I haven't encountered before; I set up a document in InDesign and my margins are correct on all of my document pages, but when I click on the Master page they are not showing up.

I checked Margins & Columns from the Master page and they appear to be correct, but again, no pink and purple guides. Guides are turned on and nothing is hidden. I even tried to just work around it by placing the elements I need on the Master page on a document page, cutting, and pasting in place but when I tried it, InDesign pasted the element on the Master in a wonky spot about two inches to the right of where it was on the document page.

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: This doesnt sound like normal behaviour. Are you sure you are not missing something? Possibly the master not being applied to the pages properly or some view mode set to 'off' that prevents you from seeing the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the master pages and select both of them. Go to the layout panel at the top and select margins and columns. select that and just click okay. They should reappear